# RadioButton in codenameone chaning the checkmark or color style

Tags: radio-button, styles, codenameone

I am facing problems changing the checkmark on the radiogroup, or color, I appreciate the help
I tried the StyleBuilder, changed the font colors, but failed to change the side mark that shows the selected radiobutton

sample
[image]

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

If you have static images, you can change `RadioButton` icons through constants in your `theme.res`. The applicable constants are:

```
radioUnselectedImage
radioUnselectedDisImage
radioSelectedImage
radioSelectedDisImage
```

If you don't have static images or you want to set the images dynamically in code, you may call below (before your `RadioButton` declaration):

```
float sizeMM = 3f;
int size = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(sizeMM);
int blue = 0x73b5e3;
int white = 0xffffff;

FontImage checkedImage = FontImage.createFixed("" + FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK, FontImage.getMaterialDesignFont(),
        blue, size, size, 0);
FontImage uncheckedImage = FontImage.createFixed("" + FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK, FontImage.getMaterialDesignFont(),
        white, size, size, 0);
((DefaultLookAndFeel) UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel())
        .setRadioButtonImages(checkedImage, uncheckedImage, checkedImage, uncheckedImage);
((DefaultLookAndFeel) UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel())
        .setRadioButtonFocusImages(checkedImage, uncheckedImage, checkedImage, uncheckedImage);
```

***Note: DefaultLookAndFeel is deprecated and may cause weird behavior, use it with caution.***

Comment: In addition you can set a radio or a check box to "toggle button" mode. Then set the pressed/released and rollover icons to whatever you want.